# iis 6.0 Getting 500 server side error instead of 404

Tags: iis

I am shutting down one of my client sites. After I removed the code from test server, I tested the url and I get 500 internal server error instead of 404. "Verify if file exists" check box for the .aspx application mapping is checked on my test server. Any other ideas?

My test server is running on Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6.0

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What are the full details within the Event Viewer for the error as there are more than a few 500 error messages that may pop up.

Comment: Here are the error messages from event viewer
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/2/2013 1:28:43 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/2/2013 6:28:43 PM 
Event ID: 3e640037fab949efb679862237fdfa09 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Server cannot access application directory 'D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\clientfolder\'. 
 The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security settings.

Comment: Is this what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300416/iis-redirect-all-requests-to-one-page ?

Comment: The site is shut down permanently. Files/Code do not exist on the server any more. I expected IIS to return 404. I am wondering if any of the iis settings are messed up.

Comment: What do you mean by `shut down` the site? `Stopped site` in IIS? Stopped sites `Application Pool` in IIS? Error that matters is security related: `The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security settings`. Finally, what other sites are listening in IIS? Do you have a site listening on `All Unassigned` IPs?