# IIS server, how to config url rewriting for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, iis

Currently, the Uni only offered us an IIS server to host our php website, we want to use Laravel framework, and it did work on home page. But not on any other controllers.

Current `web.config` in my public folder is,

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />

        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My route is,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I do not know about the IIS very well, so do you get any ideas to config it to make it work?

P.S.
We do not have rights to config IIS server in camps, what we have rights to do is upload the `web.config`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same issue. After many tries and researches, I realized that `web.config` is not enough.
The path to the root folder has to be set in IIS route settings as shown in below screenshot example.[image: laravel path on IIS]. Otherwise I wasn't able to resolve the routing issue.

Comment: Thanks, this will be a problem for me, I do not have permission to visit server. Anyway, thanks very much for sharing your experience.

Comment: If you have no way to access the server, then one potential option would be to replace all links with route function.
in `web.php` give names to all routes.
then in all links/actions instead of `href="/accounts"`, use `href="{{ route('accounts') }}"`. this may help. I remember that such links were working, but at that time i didn't understand how they work, so I went with global solution presented before.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this, it is not a perfect way, but it did work.

```
<rule name="rewrite all requests to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect / to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" redirectType="Permanent" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

As I mentioned in the beginning, it is not a perfect solution, **it rewrite all urls to index.php**, so the URLs are not pretty, like,

- `a.com/login` -> `a.com/index.php/login`
- `a.com/` -> `a.com/index.php`
- `a.com/login/index.php` -> 404

Because I am not very familiar with IIS config/rewrite, there must be some better solution, so improving advice of this lines of config file will be great.

Anyway it worked in the situation that you do not have permission to set the IIS server.

It should make Laravel project or any PHP project running on any IIS server without changing the setting of server.

### Refs

- [IIS rewrite and asp.net route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)
- [redirect all to one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300416/iis-redirect-all-requests-to-one-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with this name web.config on public folder or where index.php is with this configuration :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (including ssl redirect and webp image format) :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ssl_redirection" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer> </configuration>
```