# IIS 404 Error - link to the root path without changing the URL

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis

I used to develop on an Apache server.

I built a webapp which loads the content via AJAX. When browsing the page, the URL gets dynamically updated without actually changing the page.

1. `www.domain.com/webapp/` -> webapp root
2. user clicks on link `test/`
3. JS loads `test.json` and changes URL to `www.domain.com/webapp/test/`, the folder `test/` does not exist

Of course then, the tricky part is handling page reloads or user sharing a page which is not the root page.

I've configured the `.htaccess` to use the root path as 404 document.
`ErrorDocument 404 /webapp/`. So if the user accesses `www.domain.com/webapp/test/`, the server will automatically display the content of the root directory, which is nice.

The JS is smart enough to recognize if it's on the root or not.
`www.domain.com/webapp/` -> Do nothing
`www.domain.com/webapp/test` -> load `test.json`

I hope you understood the basic mechanism of what I did. Unfortunately, it's filled with loads of confidental content, so I can't really share stuff.

**TL;DR**

The client wants to move from an Apache to IIS. So I can't use my fancy `.htaccess` anymore.
How to use a `web.config` to act exactly the same?
I could only find tutorials where it actually redirects to a dedicated `404.aspx`. **I need the server to link to the root path without changing the URL.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS: Redirect ALL requests to one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300416/iis-redirect-all-requests-to-one-page)

Comment: Just rewrite all requests that won't hit a file to the page you want, see duplicate.